# Does Apache Commons CSV framework offer a memory-efficient incremental/sequential mode for reading large files?

Tags: java, csv, memory, memory-management, apache-commons-csv

The [*Apache Commons CSV*](https://commons.apache.org/csv/) project works quite well for parsing comma-separates values, tab-delimited data, and similar data formats.

My impression is that this tool reads a file entirely with the resulting line objects kept in memory. But I am not sure, I cannot find any documentation with regard to this behavior.

For parsing very large, I should like to do an incremental read, one line at a time, or perhaps a relatively small number of lines at a time, to avoid overwhelming memory limitations.

With regard only to the aspect of memory usage, the idea here is like how a SAX parser for XML reads incrementally to minimize use of RAM versus a DOM style XML parser that reads a document entirely into memory to provide tree-traversal.

Questions:

- What is the default behavior of Apache Commons CSV with regard to reading documents: Entirely into memory, or incremental?
- Can this behavior be altered between incremental and entire-document?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> My impression is that this tool reads a file entirely with the resulting line objects kept in memory

No. The use of memory is governed by how you choose to interact with your `CSVParser` object.

The Javadoc for [`CSVParser`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVParser.html) addresses this issue explicitly, in its sections *Parsing record wise* versus *Parsing into memory*, with a caution:

> Parsing into memory may consume a lot of system resources depending on the input. For example if you're parsing a 150MB file of CSV data the contents will be read completely into memory.

I took a quick glance at the source code, and indeed parsing record wise seems to be reading from its input source a chunk at a time, not all at once. But [see for yourself](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=commons-csv.git;a=tree).

## Parsing record wise

In section *Parsing record wise*, it shows how to incrementally read one `CSVRecord` at a time by looping the [`Iterable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html?is-external=true) that is `CSVParser`.

```
CSVParser parser = CSVParser.parse(csvData, CSVFormat.RFC4180);
for (CSVRecord csvRecord : parser) {
    ...
}
```

## Parsing into memory

In contrast, the *Parsing into memory* section shows the use of [`CSVParser::getRecords`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVParser.html#getRecords--) to load all the `CSVRecord` objects into a `List` all at once, in memory. So obviously a very large input file could blow out memory on a constrained machine.

```
Reader in = new StringReader("a;b\nc;d");
CSVParser parser = new CSVParser(in, CSVFormat.EXCEL);
List<CSVRecord> list = parser.getRecords();
```